# xcodebuild error in Xcode14.3 with argument DSTROOT

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, xcode14.3

We are having a tool which internally create iPhone build using xcodebuild command line tool. It all working fine until Xcode14.3 release. Below is my build command[image]

It uses SYMROOT and DSTROOT parameters to copy the build to a specific location in the project.

```
buildOutput=$PWD"/"$relativePath"/output"
relativePath is actually the path towards my iOS project
```

All other parameters are passing and working correctly. But when I use `DSTROOT` I am getting below error

> xcodebuild: error: “InstallationBuildProductsLocation” couldn’t be
> moved to “AdHoc 09-05-2023, 4.26 pm 2.xcarchive” because either the
> former doesn’t exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn’t
> exist.: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory

Below are the full error stack

```
2023-05-09 16:26:55.609 xcodebuild[24614:1420687] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/vt/bxdl1j6x111fjsjmw5r11s680000gn/T/ResultBundle_2023-09-05_4-26-0055 pm.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: “InstallationBuildProductsLocation” couldn’t be moved to “AdHoc 09-05-2023, 4.26 pm 2.xcarchive” because either the former doesn’t exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn’t exist.: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
```

but to my surprise, under the `output` directory I can see the .app generated `(output/Applications/myApp.app)` I am not sure why the build fails in this case. Because of the fail, I cannot proceed to next step of my build script. Could anyone please help me? I am spent lots of time but unable to find the reason behind this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I started getting the exactly same error message from my library build script, after I updated my system to macOS 13.x and to Xcode 14.x (from macOS 12.x and Xcode 13.x)

By trial and error I came to the conclusion that the new Xcode stopped "liking" to have SYMROOT and DSTROOT paths/content separated from the Derived Data path/content when archiving my library products for distribution.

What worked for me was to start using `derivedDataPath` and `archivePath` instead of `SYMROOT` and `DSTROOT`.

Like so:

```
 xcodebuild -workspace $product.xcworkspace -scheme $scheme -destination "generic/platform=iOS" clean archive -quiet ENABLE_BITCODE=NO OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS='$(inherited) -D EXTERNAL' SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES -derivedDataPath $(PWD)/tmp-derived-data -archivePath $(PWD)/tmp-derived-data/$productName
 if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
     echo "Success"
 else
     echo "Failed"
     error_exit "Error: Exit code: $?"
 fi
```

I can now find the built framework product at a slightly different location than before:

```
tmp-derived-data/$product.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/$productName.framework
```

Maybe this will help you with your problem as well.

This is what I had before:

```
xcodebuild -workspace $productName.xcworkspace -scheme $scheme -destination "generic/platform=iOS" clean archive -quiet SYMROOT=$(PWD)/tmp-build-symroot DSTROOT=$(PWD)/tmp-build-dstroot ENABLE_BITCODE=NO OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS='$(inherited) -D EXTERNAL' SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

Comment: many thanks for your suggestion, I will definitely give a try the above suggestion. Mean time I tried with 'build' instead of 'archive' in the build script and it was working fine. My intention is to generate an ipa from .app . Many thanks for your input, I really appreciate it